# DFT CPU vs GPU: flag missing

Tags: c++, opencv, dft

In my `CPU` [version](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gadd6cf9baf2b8b704a11b5f04aaf4f39d) I want to have my input as complex and I can do it like so:

`dft(srcN_gray, srcN_fft, cv::DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)`;

But when I looked at `cv::cuda` [version](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d88/group__cudaarithm__arithm.html#gadea99cb15a715c983bcc2870d65a2e78), there's a flag to specify that output `DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT` missing.

In that case how can get a complex output from `dft` on `cuda`?

Comment: I might be missing a point here, but complex _output_ is pretty much the default for an FFT. Specifying a real _input_ is just shorthand for saying "all imaginary parts of the input are zero".

Comment: @MSalters that what I'm thinking, I've to check it.. but why there is a different flag between CPU and cuda implementation?

Comment: Looking at the non-CUDA variant, it looks to me like that particular flag is ... weird. Let's call it that, weird. It seems the choice is between complex and "complex but masquerading as real".  No surprise that CUDA just went for "math says it's complex, so it's complex".

Comment: In cufft, in the case of real input, since fft illustrates symmetry, half of the array is computed. If opencv implementations builds on top of it, there might be some fishy issues.